# Adding obstacle between the turtles

Tags: wireless, netlogo

I am new to the Netlogo environment and I am trying to develop a model for wireless communication. I came across one problem where I have to block the communication between two nodes( turtles) in such a way that if  i keep an obstacle in between the two nodes ( as a patch with some color or something like that), the transmitting node should scan the obstacle and reports something to end the procedure. I went through the Line of sight model  and the obstacle avoidance model in the Netlogo community but they are of little help to me. The node is supposed to scan the obstacle not in a range of one patch ahead only but for the whole distance between itself and the other node. Any ideas or primitives suitable for this problem would be of great help to me. I hope I have made it clear and sorry about my English :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not the most efficient solution, but assuming you have the following breeds:

```
breed [ obstacles obstacle ]
breed [ nodes node ]
```

You can use the following reporter:

```
to-report can-see? [ target ]
  let result false
  hatch 1 [
    face target
    fd 0.1
    set result ifelse-value (any? turtles-here with [ self = target ])
      [ true ]
      [ ifelse-value (any? obstacles-here)
        [ false ]
        [ can-see? target ]
      ]
    die
  ]
  report result
end
```

It works by [`hatch`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#hatch)ing a whole series of temporary nodes in direction of the target. If any node along the way encounters an obstacle it returns `false`. If it reaches the target, it returns `true`. Those temporary nodes are created recursively until a result is obtained.

You might want to adjust the "step size" (`fd 0.1` in this example): a greater step size will be more likely to miss the corner of an obstacle, but slightly faster.

You will also want to make sure that you use [tick based updates instead of continuous updates](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#updates), or it will be very slow.

Here is an example that creates links between nodes that can see each other:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 100 patches [
    sprout-obstacles 1 [
      set color red
      set shape "square"
    ]
  ]
  ask n-of 50 patches with [ not any? obstacles-here ] [ 
    sprout-nodes 1 [
      set color yellow
      set shape "circle"
      let targets other nodes
      create-links-with targets with [ can-see? myself ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

If you want to use patches instead of turtles as obstacles, you can probably modify it fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this answer to this question on the NetLogo Users list. Reposting here for completeness:

There are many methods that might work.

My first thought was of the "Intersecting Lines" example in the Models Library. One could consider an obstacle as an X of lines on the patch. That being the case, it seems it would be possible to use the same techniques to find whether the line between the nodes intersects any of the lines on the obstacles.

This seems like a good way to find all network lines of sight that are blocked by obstacles. The method is pretty fast and might be improved (test!) by first finding the obstacles within the radius defined by the source and destination nodes.

Here are other ideas.

Another way is to send a turtle out to "walk" the straight path toward the other node, to discover any obstacles. This has to be done carefully, to avoid jumping over the corners of patches intersecting the line.

Another is to use the same methods, but without a turtle, just using math to find the "next" patch, and move along the line.

Another is to use IN-CONE with a very small angle to get a narrow set of patches between the nodes. One could find the intersection of the IN-CONE from A to B and the IN-CONE from B to A, to narrow down the set. Then search the set for obstacles or use MIN-ONE OF with DISTANCE on the set to find the "nearest" obstacle.

Another is to use geometry / maths to find the set of patches that lie on the line between the two nodes then look for obstacles.